# Code fails in plugin file but works in functions.php

Tags: plugins, functions

I want to use the following code in my main php plugin file.
I get a whole screen full of error messages.

When I put it in functions.php it works fine.
Can someone advise please?

```
$pages = get_posts($args);

foreach($pages as $page) {

    $out = get_permalink($page->ID);
}
```

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you have done, no one can tell you what you are doing wrong

Comment: You're passing in an array named `$args`, but you haven't included that in your question, can you edit your question to include the missing code?

Comment: This is the complete code      $args = array(
           'orderby' => 'post_title',
           'order' => 'ASC',
           'post_type' => 'page',
           'showposts' => 1000,
           'caller_get_posts' => 1
       );
     $pages = get_posts($args);

       foreach($pages as $page) {
           $out = get_permalink($page->ID);
       }

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a hook and a function in your plugin file. 
For example:

```
function sher_posts() {

    $pages = get_posts($args);

    foreach($pages as $page) {

        $out = get_permalink($page->ID);
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'sher_posts');
```

Of course this example doesn't know what `$args` are or what to do with `$out`.

Comment: while in general you should hook your code on an action or filter, I don't see any reason why should that code not work at plugin load time in the global context.